# SDK Вконтакте Android. Нужно получить информацию о пользователях с помощью метода ВК API users.get

Tags: java, вконтакте, запрос, sdk, android-vksdk

У меня в приложении пользователь авторизуется в ВК с помощью метода `VK.login(this, list);` и получает объект `VKAccessToken`. Как используя SDK методы я теперь могу послать запрос `users.get` и в каком виде приходит ответ?

Comment: А в документации не написано?

Comment: написано, но там на языке Kotlin, а я пока ещё только Java изучаю ( и гугл как назло ничего не выдаёт

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK  и  https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk   Никаких котлинов не вижу

Comment: первая ссылка это Java а мне нужно для Java Android, я так поняла там разные SDK, а по второй ссылке там всё на Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем пришлось мне книгу про Kotlin прочитать что бы разобраться.
Когда мы получили токен и хотим отправить запрос то нужно создать объект с запросом.
В Java это выглядит так

```
VKRequest vkRequest = new VKRequest("likes.add").addParam("type","post").addParam("owner_id",227420921).addParam("item_id", 21374).addParam("access_key", vkAccessToken.getAccessToken()).addParam("v", "5.130");
```

Создаём объект `VKRequest` и при создании в конструктор закидываем сам метод, а дальше с помощью методов addParam закидываем в объект параметры для запроса. В примере мы хотим поставить лайк на стене пользователя. `vkAccessToken.getAccessToken()` - тут мы указываем токен полученный ранее.

После того как мы получили объект `vkRequest` нужно его отправить на сервак, это делается с помощью метода `VK.execute()`

```
 VK.execute(vkRequest, new VKApiCallback(){

                @Override
                public void success(Object o) {
                 //какие то действия с полученной информацией
                }

                @Override
                public void fail(@NotNull VKApiExecutionException e) {
                 //какие то действия с полученной информацией
                }
            });
```

В метод VK.execute() мы запихиваем созданный нами объект и анонимный класс в котором переопределяем методы. Эти методы будут вызываться после того как сервер обработает запрос. success вызывается когда запрос обработан и получен ответ, а fail в случае если произошла ошибка при отправке запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку на данный момент до сих пор нигде нет примеров по новому SDK, пришлось насобирать по кусочкам и обрывочным сведениям в интернете java-код использования в качестве SSO (логин и получение userId) на SDK com.vk:android-sdk-core:3.3.0

Полостью код положил на страницу официального SDK [сюда](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/issues/491)

Вкратце:

```
VKRequest r = new VKRequest("users.get",VK.getApiVersion()).addParam("fields","city, domain, nickname,photo_100,sex");
VK.execute(r, new VKApiCallback<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(JSONObject response) {
... //тут используем  response как обычно
```